# CSS font-weight issue in body tag

Tags: html, css, fonts

i've been having a small issue with the font-weight property, when I put it into the body tag, it doesn't seem to work.(I have a < h1 > tag in my HTML which I don't want in bold). Of course if I would put the **font-weight:normal;** property inside the " * " it works. But it doesn't when I leave in the body. I know I can just use a h1 tag and put the font properties in there, but I'm curious as to why it isn't working for me.

Thanks , and here is my CSS code.

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;


}
body {
background-color: #DCDBD9;
color: #2C2C2C;
font-weight:normal; /*this doesn't seem to work*/
font-size:100%;
font-family: Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: If you don't explicitly override the default styling for an H1 tag, the browser will render the H1 using whatever the default options are.

Comment: The `font-weight` for `h1` is more specific than the `font-weight` of `body`. If you want to override the `font-weight` of `h1`, add `h1{font-weight:normal;}` to your CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The `*` selector will explicitely set the `font-weight` to each individual element, thus overriding the default `font-weight:bold` of an `h1`
- Setting `font-weight:normal` to body won't change a thing, since the default `font-weight` value for `body`*is* normal.
- The `font-weight` property on body won't be inherited by children who have a browser default font-weight, such as an `<h1>` or a `<strong>` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't aware that the `*` selector sets the properties for each individual element. Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just put the `font-weight:normal` in an `h1` section of your CSS?

Comment: @MatthewGreen OP mentioned the following in his question: *I know I can just use a h1 tag and put the font properties in there, but I'm curious as to why it isn't working for me.*